# Ubuntu size, and applying it as well as I can

Tags: disk-usage

I have a laptop from 08, which had Vista on it. At some point, (likely 2011ish) I installed Ubuntu onto the laptop, as well as keeping the Vista OS. Regardless, when Vista died, I was able to extract Vista files via Ubuntu. That's the history of the computer.

After a while, I attempted to re-install Vista onto the laptop, which just wouldn't happen. So, I obtained a 32gb Thumb-drive, and installed the maximum number of GB downloadable possible of Ubuntu on the Thumb-drive, to install onto the laptop, as a standalone OS.

My question, in it's entirety.. bears my curiosity around whether I have a "32GB" type Ubuntu.. or if it expanded on it's own. In essence, if I can allow Ubuntu to work off of my computer, rather than the file size I had allocated on the thumb-drive, in order to get a faster, more responsive experience.

- As an example, if I had downloaded the 2GB sized Ubuntu, and installed it only this computer.. is that end result different from the 30ish GB download? I'd like to know if my computer still has "space" for more Ubuntu. When I had both Vista and Ubuntu at once, I feel there isn't too much of a difference revolving around my current Ubuntu experience, when it stands alone on this laptop.

Hopefully I clarified my question. I wanted to know if Ubuntu expanded, using the computer in it's entirety.. or if it's capped based on what was contained with that 30GB ish download size, which I imported onto a thumb-drive to install onto this laptop.

Thank you for any assistance or knowledge on the matter. It's greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean 32-bit, which has nothing to do with file size or hard drives. 32-bit with PAE only allows programs to use up to 4GB of RAM, and only 32-bits of memory access at a time. 64-bit allows you to use an amount of RAM so great that for the hardware of the foreseeable future, it might as well be infinite. There's no limit to how much hard drive space you can use. I have mine installed with a total of 7000GB combined hard drive space.